# GA4: Can I find out which pages users viewed across 2 sessions?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I'm trying to find out which pages a cohort of users visit across 2 sessions.

Either A) Of the users who visited a particular webpage in session 1, what webpages do they visit in session 2 (on another day)?

Or B) when a webpage is visited on session 1, what pages do the same returning users visit in other sessions?

I have tried cohort analysis, but it seems to give only the number of users within a cohort, and there is no way to identify which pages they visit across the different sessions.

Also tried page flow analysis, but this is immediate next pages and not across 2 sessions.

Any ideas if this is possible in GA4?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Add the dimension 'page location' breakdown. More importantly, add the correct segment through the 'add sequence to include' for a time series analysis